# Recovering Postgres DB from Program Files

Tags: sql, postgresql

a few weeks ago my computer stopped working and I lost a lot of important data stored in a postgres DB (should have backed it up but, I didn't ** sigh ** ).
I was able to access the hard drive and extract the program files for postgres. How can I try and restore the DB?

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. download postgres (same version as the lost DB) on a separate computer and swap out the program files with the ones I am trying to recover. I am using a PC, so I stop service->swap out all the files-> restart service. Restarting the service is never successful.
2. Use PGAdmin -> creat new db (ensure path for binary files is correct) -> restore-> Here i get stuck figuring out what the correct files are

Comment: If you can install the same version, just replace the entire data tree with the one from your old disk.

Comment: replacing just the data folder worked! Haha I feel stupid. Thank you!